# Newbie about Flask: activation

Tags: python, flask

Does everytime I want to activate my Flask project, I have to run 'sudo pip install flask? What's the step by step when I have already my project created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install flask` is just for installing the Flask package to your Python installation. Running it more than once, assuming you didn't delete the files, will not help you.

Running your project depends on how your code is laid out, but most tutorials end up with having you run `python app.py` in the terminal to run the app. See the official tutorial for an example: [Installation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/installation/#installation), and [running the app](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#a-minimal-application).

Comment: So, everytime i want to work on my project, i have only to cd (myproject) / source bin/activate?

Comment: So you're using `virtualenv`. To activate that environment, yes, run `source bin/activate`. Depending on your OS, you'll see a clear notation in your terminal prompt that denotes you being in that environment. From there, `python app.py` to run the app.

Answer (score 1):

When facing a problem with `pip install` or `no module found flask` try the following: (From the youtube video I found by TheTruthPenguin):

When using windows 10+:

Try the following in CMD:

```
py -m pip
```

This should tell you if you have pip installed or not. If you have PIP, this will print out a helpful page listing the common commands. If you don't have PIP, install PIP first.

If pip is out of date, try the following:

```
py -m pip install - - upgrade pip
```

(Important Edit:10/11/20:
Using `py -m pip install -- upgrade pip` gave me a error and warning with instructions to fix.
Instead of py, use Python. So try:
`python -m pip install - - upgrade pip` if nothing else in this comment works.)

To install a specific python package modules, type:

```
py -m pip install send2trash
```

Replace `sendToTrash` with whatever module you are looking for, in this case, `flask`.

Comment: Hey, this is a helpful comment, but its not really an "answer" to the original question. Might be better as a comment in future. However since Stack Overflow doesn't allow new people to comment I can't really blame you for adding it as an answer.

Comment: @O'Rooney actually i am new to stack overflow and was searching for this solution but couldn't find and when i found this , i thought to add in that thread which had pip installation problem regarding talks , but couldn't so thought to post here in this thread since it was also related to flask installation issues, and apologies i am newbie too 

Answer (score 0):

I'm mostly talking of a linux environment, but you probably want `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`.

```
$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 flask_ve
$ pip install flask
$ pip freeze > [your_project_dir]/requirements.txt
```

When you're done, you can do `deactivate` and then when you come back to your project, just do `workon your_virtualenv_name`. When you add a requirement just update the `requirements.txt` file by doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt`